# Where does Linux install Pocketsphinx program?

Tags: location, installation, pocketsphinx

I am new in Linux and don't know much about it's installation manner. It's interesting for me to know where does it install the `pockesphinx` program?
where is `continuous.c`file?
How Linux can find and execute this command: `pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where stuff is installed depends on how it was installed. Usually: If you were using your package manager, refer to your distrobutions documentation. If you extracted a tarball or installed using a script from a projects website, refer to their documentation.

If you are able to invoke the program from your terminal from everywhere, it will probably reside somewhere on your $PATH. You can show which directories are included in your path by issuing `cat $PATH` in your terminal of choice.

Also, the `locate` command is useful if you need to locate a file on your disk. I.e. `locate pocketsphinx` would give you all files that has the pocketsphinx string in its name, and its location. If you just installed the program, you might need to run a `sudo updatedb` to rebuild the index.

Comment: Thanks Karl, but when I use `locate` it says `-bash: locate: command not found`

Comment: You will probably need to install locate. Which distro are you using? If you are using ubuntu you can run `sudo apt install mlocate`

Comment: Thanks, I did what you said but I got this error: `locate: can not stat () `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db': No such file or directory`

Comment: You are missing the database that mlocate uses to keep track of what files are where, try running `sudo updatedb`. This command is probably run every night by the system (depending on your distro), but sometimes you would like to manually run it (i.e., if you just installed something, or did a lot of moving files around).